# Check if the integral diverges.

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with calculatig this specific integral:
$$\int_1^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1 + x^3}}$$
Any  piece of advice on how to get this one done?

Comment: Bound above by an easy-to-integrate function.

Comment: Hint: $\left | \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1 + x^3}} \right |\le \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$

Comment: By *calculating* you mean computing a closed form for such integral, or just proving it is convergent? One problem is intractable, the other one is trivial.

Comment: nah, it was about proving it was convergent. I got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}\le\frac1{x^{3/2}}\;\;,\;\;\;\text{and since}\;\;\int_1^\infty x^pdx\;\;\text{converges}\;\;\iff p<-1$$

then....

Comment: Is  it obvious that this inequality holds?

Comment: @Fabian Well, we know $\;|\sin x|\le 1\implies \sin^2x\le 1\;$ , and in the **positive** ray $\;[1,\infty)\;$ , we have that $\;\sqrt{1+x^3}\ge\sqrt{x^3}\;$ , so I'd rather say it is pretty trivial.

Comment: @Fabian Yes, it is.  And (+1) for the concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is always positive for $x\in[1,\infty)$, so the only potential problem is when $x\rightarrow\infty$.

However, we have $\sin^2(x)\leq1$ and since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}<\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$, your integral is convergent.